# Load variable from a file & pass as arg value in ant build

Tags: apache-flex, ant, build-automation

What I want to do is load the contents of a file and sent it to an mxmlc compiler as an argument parameter.
I can load and read the contents of a file using `loadfile` and setting a `property` value say `propery="filecontent"`. But the problem is I can pass it into the mxmlc (flex) compiler.
I'm not able to pass it (tried with `${filecontent}`) to the `arg line`. Its gives an error: "value contains unknown token 'filecontent'"
How will I pass the contents of the file as a argument value to a compiler argument?
Edit:
The problem is with the `include-resource-bundles` arguments. When using command line it works. But using ant build doesn't. Do we need to manually provide the name of resource bundles by generating the resource file?

```
<exec executable="${MXMLC}" dir="${APP_ROOT}/src" >
    <arg line="-locale 'en_US'"/>
  .. .. ..
    <arg line="-include-resource-bundles 'collections,components,containers,controls,core,effects,formatters,layout,modules,skins,states,styles'"/>
    .. ..
```

I'm trying to replace the arguments via something like:

```
... ....
<loadfile property="resources" srcFile="${APP_ROOT}/src/resources.txt"/>
... ....
<exec executable="${MXMLC}" dir="${APP_ROOT}/src" >
  ...
    <arg line="-include-resource-bundles '${resources}'"/>
  ....
</exec>
```

which doesn't work and gives and error -> `command line: Error: configuration variable 'include-resource-bundles' value contains unknown token 'resources'`

So how to automate this?

Comment: Can you post the relevant parts of the build.xml? a) where you read the file b) where you call mxmlc

Comment: okay, edited and added more details.

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing obviously wrong with the build file.  But the error message suggests that `${resources}` is not set when you call the MXMLC compiler.  When an Ant property is not set, the property name (with dollar sign and enclosing curly brackets) is substituted instead anywhere that the property is used.

Can you insert something like

```
<echo message="Resources: ${resources}" />
```

after the 'loadfile' to check that that task is working?  Note, for example, that if the resources.txt is empty the property will not be set.

Comment: While using echo the file contents are being echoed. Its actually storing it in the variable. Just that the mxmlc compiler couldn't get it from the property variable. `-include-resource-bundles` accepts multiple resource names when used in command line. But seems like using ant build its not being able to use like that. Some wired problem.